# Number of ways to form a Board of Representatives

Tags: combinatorics

A board of representatives for a local university is to be formed from a pool of five professionals. The board will consist of a chair, a vice-chair, and one additional member.

(a) In how many ways may the board be formed?

Is this 5C3 or 5P3?

(b) If the board will be formed from a pool of ten applicants, with a chair, a vice-chair, and three additional members, in how many ways may the board be formed?

10C6 or 10P6?

(c) Suppose that two of the professionals in the part (b) refuse to serve as the vice-chair. In how many ways may the committee then be formed?

I'm not sure how to do this one.

Comment: Part (b) does not refer to professionals.

Comment: Oh so it'd be out of 10. Also, are these permutation or combination questions? I'm not sure if order matters?

Comment: Part (a), clearly order matter, so permutation. Part (b) is a mix of both. Start by choosing chair and vice-chair (order matters) then three members (order doesn't matter). Part (c) choose vice-chair first.

Comment: So (a) is 5 P 2 * 3C1 and (b) is 10P2 * 8C3?

Comment: Your revised answers to parts (a) and (b) are correct.

Comment: Yay! Thanks and (c) is 8P1 * 9P1*7C3?

Answer (score 1):

Combinations are used when we are selecting a subset, that is, when the order of selection does not matter.  Permutations are used when we are counting arrangements, that is, when order matters.

> A board of representatives for a local university is to be formed from a pool of five professionals. The board will consist of a chair, a vice-chair, and one additional member.  In how many ways may the board be formed?

There are five ways to choose the chair, four ways to choose the vice-chair from among the remaining members of the pool, and three ways to choose the additional member from the remaining members of the pool.  Hence, by the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), the number of ways the board can be formed is 
$$5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$$
Notice that 
$$5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{5!}{2!} = \frac{5!}{(5 - 3)!} = P(5, 3)$$
Since it matters which person occupies which position, order matters.  Therefore, this is a permutation problem.

> If the board will be formed from a pool of ten applicants, with a chair, a vice-chair, and three additional members, in how many ways may the board be formed?

There are $10$ ways to choose the chair and $9$ ways to choose the vice-chair from the remaining members of the pool.  We then need to select three of the eight remaining members of the pool to be additional members, which can be done in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.  The order in which the additional members are selected does not matter since they do not serve in roles with different responsibilities.  Hence, the number of ways the board can be formed is 
$$10 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{8}{3}$$

> Suppose that two of the professionals in the part (b) refuse to serve as the vice-chair. In how many ways may the committee then be formed?

Since two of the ten people will not accept the vice-chair position, there are eight ways to fill the vice-chair position, leaving nine ways to choose the chair from among the remaining members of the pool.  The three additional members can be selected from among the remaining eight members of the pool in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.  Hence, the number of ways the board can be formed is 
$$8 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{8}{3}$$

Comment: Oh I thought (c) would be 8C1 * 9C1 * 7C3... I see why it's not. Thanks so much!